# Nested function overloading in Swift

Tags: swift, methods, user-defined-functions, overloading

Overloading methods in Swift works as expected, but when I try to overload nested functions, such as

```
func foo() {
    func bar(param: Int) {
        // do stuff
    }
    func bar(param: Double) {
        // do stuff
    }

    // call functions here
}
```

I get an error saying `Definition conflicts with previous value`. Why does this happen?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the following gives the identical error, so it's probably a case of treating them as local identifiers bound to clousres: `func foo() -> (Int) -> () {
    let bar: (Int) -> () = { (param: Int) in println(param) }
    let bar: (String) -> () = { (param: String) in println(param) }

    return bar
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO this is clearer if you consider this variation:

```
func foo() {

    let bar: (param: Int) -> () = { p in
        // do stuff
    }

    func bar(param: Double) {
        // do stuff
    }

    // call functions here
}
```

With your first `bar` function definition you are just declaring a constant of type `(param: Int) -> ()`.
Thus with your second declaration you are declaring another constant of different type `(param: Double) -> ()` but having the same name as the already declared `bar`.

In short it's just like you wrote:

```
let bar: Int = 0
let bar: Double = 0.0
```

In which case compiler will complain as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, this means that global functions are not of the same nature as nested functions. This is not documented (I didn't find something about this). Nested functions are lambdas/closures which globals are not.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Honestly I can't tell if it is formally correct that global functions are not lambdas. Anyway global functions do not _close_. From the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) global functions _are defined at a global scope_ (the do not have an _outer_ scope to close on). Meanwhile for nested functions: _An enclosing function can also return one of its nested functions_. Thus a nested function closes around its context.
Maybe documentation just do not use formal language used in other contexts.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The doc is too poor, there is a lack of formal definition of Swift, or did I miss something?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès IMHO the docs are pretty good if you take into account the fact that the language is still evolving. Moreover the doc is intended for people coming from any other background ... or no background at all. This might explain why the docs might appear too poor to someone, and too complex for others. If you have some spare time, you might appreciate this talk [https://youtu.be/BVFtrrXhApw](https://youtu.be/BVFtrrXhApw). It refers to the transition from Obj-C and Swift, but it is way more general ... and funny ;-)

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès By the way, if you are looking for more advanced details about the language, you might find really helpful the upcoming book [Advanced Swift](https://www.objc.io/books/advanced-swift/). Chris Eidhof has a functional programming background in Haskell. Also Airspeed Velocity is very competent about Swift. Both follow Swift from the beginning.

Comment: Thousands thanks Matteo! Hope to be able to send you something at least useful for you some day!

Comment: Why wait? Do something useful for someone else in my name, and we are even ;-)

Comment: Exactly! I'll do it almost everyday.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

Note that this behaviour/restriction is not documented and the answer is my best guess.

Consider this following piece of code:

```
func foo() -> (param:Int)->() {
    func bar(param: Int) {
        // do stuff
    }
    return bar
}
```

The function will return the closure `bar`. If you were to have another closure named `bar` within the same function, like this...

```
func foo() -> (param:Int)->() {
    func bar(param: Int) {
        // do stuff
    }
    func bar(param: Float) {
        // do stuff
    }
    return bar
}
```

...they would have conflicting names and the compiler doesn't know what to return. This is same as the following piece of code which you would readily agree to be wrong:

```
func foo() -> Int {
    let a:Int = 0
    let a:Int = 0 //Error
    return a
}
```

**More observation**

The behaviour of a similar set of functions inside a class is weird.

```
class Test {
    func foo(param:Float) {
        let bar = { (param:Int) -> () in
            //do stuff
        }
    }
    func foo(param:Int) {
        let bar = { (param:Int) -> () in
            //do stuff
        }
    }
    func anotherFoo() {
        println(self.foo) //Compile time error - Ambiguous use of foo
    }
}
```

All though...

```
class Test {
    func foo(param:Float) {
        let bar = { (param:Int) -> () in
            //do stuff
        }
    }
    func anotherFoo() {
        println(self.foo) //Compiles
    }
}
```

Interesting.

Comment: Swift mangles the function/method(in terms of a class) names and as the parameter of bar function is different(one is Int and the other is Double) there shouldn't be conflict.

Comment: Makes sense now. Did some experiments.

Comment: @avismara After your second code block you say that the compiler would not know what to return, but there's no reason for that to be true. The compiler is aware that the function must return something of the type `(Int)->()`, so when you try to return simply `bar` there should be no ambiguity. There is only one entity named `bar` of the correct type. This ability to resolve ambiguity based on types is the point of function overloading. So I still don't think we've found a satisfactory answer as to why function overloading doesn't work in a nested scope.

Comment: Now that I think about it after 3 years, you're right. This is like reading your old code :D
 But, the accepted answer makes sense, no?